# How to install Ubuntu on a IBM R31 Thinkpad

Tags: boot, system-installation

I recently acquired an old IBM R31 Thinkpad, and I'd figure I'd install Lubuntu on it. I've followed the quick steps for USB installation on the help wiki page, but I can't seem to get it to boot from my formatted flash drive.

I've checked the boot priority on the BIOS page, but the option to boot from USB doesn't even seem to be there. The only bootable options are legacy and USB floppy drives. The CD drive is shot, so I can't install from there either. Do I have any other options for installation without having to pay for a floppy drive or a replacement CD drive?

The wiki pages mentions something about installation from within Windows. Would it be possible to remove Windows using this option, or would it just create a partition?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`netboot`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot).It will allows you to install ubuntu on your PC through network.

Answer (score 0):

If your R31 has the same BIOS as the (same generation) X30, then bootable USB devices are actually listed under the `Hard Drive` menu item rather than the more obvious `Removable Devices` menu

[image: X30 boot menu]